# Распознавание таблиц на Python

Tags: python, opencv, таблицы, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Мне надо сделать распознавание текста в таблице. Я пробовал для этого tesseract,но он совсем не помог.[!Пример картинки, которую я загружал в программу, но она вернула пустой результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaNYL.jpg"")][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaNYL.jpg"")

Вот код моей программы. Входные параметры: название изображения, название конечного документа и его формат

```py
from PIL import Image
import sys
from fpdf import FPDF
from docx import Document
import pytesseract as tess
def recognize(image):
   return tess.image_to_string(Image.open(image),config='-c preserve_interword_spaces=1')


def to_pdf():
   pdf = FPDF()
   pdf.add_page()
   pdf.set_font("Arial",size = 12)
   pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=recognize(sys.argv[1]),ln = 1, align="L")
   pdf.output(str(sys.argv[2])+".pdf")

def to_word():
   doc = Document()
   print(recognize(sys.argv[1]))
   doc.add_paragraph(recognize(sys.argv[1]))
   doc.save(str(sys.argv[2])+".docx")

def to_txt():
   f = open(str(sys.argv[2])+".txt","w+")
   f.write(recognize(sys.argv[1]))
   f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   if sys.argv[3] == "pdf":
   to_pdf()
   elif sys.argv[3] == "docx":
   to_word()
   else:
   to_txt()
```

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы программа работала правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После двух дней поиска информации я нашел этот репозиторий
https://github.com/brian-yang/table-parser-opencv/blob/master/main.py